# Split and rejoin path without trailing backslash

Tags: file, python-2.7, path, split

New to Python, when I Frankensplice* a path, I'm pick up an extra backslash. Not sure why. I'm aware that it prints out as '\' in the raw state. This is happening on a Windows machine.

*(split it and then put it back together again)

Here's what I have

```
import os

f = "C:\\Gwen\\Stefani\\This is bananas.txt"

fname, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
head, tail = os.path.split(fname)

# strip last slash
tail = tail.rstrip("\\")

print ("%r" % (f))    # 'C:\\Gwen\\Stefani\\This is bananas.txt'
print ("%r" % (head)) # 'C:\\Gwen\\Stefani'
print ("%r" % (tail)) # 'This is bananas'
print ("%r" % (ext))  # '.txt'

# join them again
r = os.path.join(head, tail, ext)
print ("%r" % (r)) # 'C:\\Gwen\\Stefani\\This is bananas\\.txt'
```

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: @holroy I'm actually debugging stuff, there's a function that changes the case on the filename, which I've not included here. As for results? I'd expect to end up with what I started with, f == r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `os.path.split` splits the "path\file", all the backslashes are removed, so there is no need to do the `tail.rstrip("\\")`.

Further, when adding them back to get the identical text you need to do the following:

```
r = os.path.join(head, tail, fname + ext)
```

This is because `os.path.join` joins path elements, and can't possibly know that you are suddenly introducing only part of a filename (the `.ext`). In other words, you need to concatenate the filename before joining to the complete filepath.  (This is the reverse of your need to use `splitext` to split the filename... )

Answer (score 0):

from the docs for `os.path.join(path,*paths)`:
The return value is the concatenation of path and any members of *paths with exactly **one directory separator (os.sep) following each non-empty part except the last**, meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last part is empty.